# Чтобы отобразить эту страницу, Firefox должен отправить информацию для повторения ранее произведённого действия

Tags: php, html, веб-программирование

Создал форму (method="post"), при перезагрузке страницы появляется такое вот окошечко. Хотелось бы понять из-за чего оно появляется и как сделать чтобы оно не появлялось.
[image: Firefox Warning]

Comment: нужно сбрасывать метод POST: `header('Location: ?');` Вместо знака ? возможно понадобится указать корректный адрес.